# AVPlayer removing a periodicTimeObserver

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, observers

I'm having difficulty stopping an AVPlayers time observer.

I have an AVPlayer player running like this:

```
player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

then I add an observer

```
    [player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(3, 10) queue:NULL usingBlock:^(CMTime time){
        NSTimeInterval seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time);
    NSLog(@"observer called");
        for (NSDictionary *item in robotR33) {
            NSNumber *time = item[@"time"];
            if ( seconds > [time doubleValue] && [time doubleValue] >= [lastTime doubleValue] ) {
               // NSLog(@"LastTime: %qi", [lastTime longLongValue]);
                lastTime = @(seconds);
                NSString *str = item[@"line"];
                [weakSelf nextLine:str];
               // NSLog(@"item: %qi", [time longLongValue]);
               // NSLog(@"Seconds: %f", seconds)
            };
        }
    }];
    [player play];
```

once I am finished with the player I do this:

```
[player pause];
[player removeTimeObserver:self.timeObserver]
player = nil;
```

the weird thing is when I put a breakpoint in the code and step through the code using XCode it works.  I can see the block stops printing out "observer code"

But when I run the code normally with no breakpoints, I can see that the observer is still running at the same interval after the [player removeTimeObserver] has been called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Glad to see weakSelf worked for you ...

In the above I don't see you assigning the result of

```
  [player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval ...
```

to  self.timeObserver  it may be a typo but it should be ;

```
   self.timeObserver =  [player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval ...
```

if you intend to call

```
   [player removeTimeObserver:self.timeObserver];
```

you also missed the ";" above.

Comment: Hi Yes thanks on both counts.  It wasn't a typo but had spotted my mistake already.  Good to have it documented here though.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just in case someone needs to create the var:
`var timeObserver: Any`

Comment: An instance of AVPlayer cannot remove a time observer that was added by a different instance of AVPlayer